# Do Rabin Fingerprints have any advantages over CRC?

Tags: hash, number-theory

**Background**

In both, bitstrings are interpreted as a polnomical over GF(2) and they each can be used to implement a hash over a sliding window. The definitions of each are as follows:

Rabin Fingerprint: $M(x) = Q(x) \cdot G(x) + R (x)$

CRC: $M(x) \cdot x^{n} = Q(x) \cdot G(x) + R (x)$

Where $M(x)$ is message polynomial, $G(x)$ is the degree-$n$ irreducible 'generator' polynomial, $x^{n}$ represents $n$ zeroes added at the end of the message, $Q(x)$ is the quotient polynomial (ignored) and $R(x)$ is the remainder polynomial (the hash itself).

**The Question**

According to page 7 (labelled as page 135) of the paper [LFSR-based Hashing and Authentication](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48658-5_15.pdf), CRC offers some improvements for hashing under encryption.

Assuming $G(x)$ is the same for the implementation of each algorithm (i.e. ignoring that polynomials under Rabin should be random) and an identical $M(x)$ is used for testing, does the Rabin Fingerprint offer any advantages over CRC? If not, is there any reason why the Rabin Fingerprint is moderately popular in file chunking (using the sliding window technique mentioned above)? For example, [1](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/lbfs/), [2](http://nsg.cs.princeton.edu/publication/czip_usenix_07.ppt) and many others on the web. By contrast, I can find very few implementations of a sliding window version of CRC or mentions of it being used for chunking.

Comment: Your statement about CRC is incorrect as far as communications systems are concerned, though it may be the way CRCs are used in cryptographic applications. In communications systems, CRCs are used _exactly_ the way you describe the Rabin fingerprint, with the transmission being $$x^nM(x)-R(x)=M_kx^{n+k}+M_{k-1}x^{n+k-1}+\cdots+M_0x^n-R_{n-1}x^{n-1}-R_{n-2}x^{n-2}-\cdots-R_0,$$ that is, the data sequence followed by the CRC sequence.

Comment: The meaning of "_$G(x)$ and $M(x)$ are the same_" is obscure to me.

Comment: As in, we use the same message and same generator polynomial as the input for both.

Answer (score 4):

This is an expanded version of my comment above.  At the top of page 135 of the paper cited by the OP, the construction of **the cryptographic CRC** is defined  in the following words:

> $\ldots$ for any message $M(x)$ of binary length $m$ bits, $h_p(M)$ 
>   is defined as (the coefficients of) $M(x)\cdot x^n \bmod p(x)$.

Thus, the definition of cryptographic CRC in the cited paper is
the **same** as what the OP **claims** the Rabin fingerprint
is. On the other hand, the cited paper says Rabin's construction
is essentially the same

> $\ldots$ except for the multiplication by $x^n$ in the modular
>   process

In other words, the OP seems to have interchanged the
definitions of CRC and Rabin fingerprint in his question.

The cited paper 
also seems to be implying (the phrasing is somewhat ambiguous)
that Rabin's fingerprint is weaker than the cryptographic CRC
defined above, which, by the way, is the same as the way CRC
error detection is used in communications systems, as I stated
in my comment.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I managed to carelessly mislabel my equations when crafting my question. I've now corrected it, thanks.

Comment: The cited paper explains that Rabin's fingerprint would be unsafe, but CRC is safe, as an authentication method, in the setting where $G(x)$ is secret and $M(x)$ $R(x)$ are sent encrypted using a stream cipher. The extra zeroes protect against a trivial attack where e.g. the low-oder bit of the (encrypted) $M(x)$ and $R(x)$ are flipped. This does not answer the question.